# How can get a selected li's next li's attributes value

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I want href value of Current-page li 's next li's vlaue , i means   individual-page named class's li's a attributes href value in jquery how can i get it.

```
<ul>
    <li class="current-page">    // selected li
        <span>1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="individual-page">
        <a href="/notebooks?pagesize=4&pagenumber=2">2</a>   // want href's value
    </li>
    <li class="individual-page">
        <a href="/notebooks?pagesize=4&pagenumber=3">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
//Select the .current-page li
$('li.current-page')

//Traverse to the next li
.next('li')

//Find the anchor inside
.find('a')

//Get the href property 
.prop('href')
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/gtrt5czd/2/)

**Documentation**

- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

use `attr()` to get href value

```
$("li.current-page").click(function(){
alert($(this).next("li").find("a").attr("href"));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/dcgv3po6/6/)

Answer (score 0):

var value = $('li.current-page').next().find('a').attr(href);

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @George's answer.

If you want to retrieve the value of same `li` everytime than you can use this also :

```
$('.individual-page').first().find('a').prop('href');
```